# How to make SASS compile upon change (watch) without npm start each time

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, sass

Working on a new React project that is using SASS.  All of the .scss files are in the src/components directory, and strangely the start script is setup like this:

```
"start": "npm-run-all -p watch:sass start:app"
```

but on the project when making a change in SCSS, we are having to ctrl-c out of the app and restart by doing `npm start` again.  Is there some misconfiguration here?  Seems like this should be watching the scss files and recompiling on the fly.

Thanks for suggestions

Comment: Can you share what `watch:sass` script is?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a front-end developer, but maybe you can use nodemon. Install it using npm i nodemon. This tool will automatically restart your server if any changes happen. Take a look here [Watch & Compile your Sass with npm](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/watch-compile-your-sass-npm-aleksandar-cvjetan/)